# Symfony2 and Doctrine - Embed Forms Collections - edit form

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, doctrine-orm

Im' trying to make edit form for one of my entity. I've created a add form successfuly, but, on edit view it doesn't work at all. I only get error:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class TA\ManagerBundle\Entity\TaReservation. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "TA\ManagerBundle\Entity\TaReservation" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class TA\ManagerBundle\Entity\TaReservation to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.

TaReservation has TaReservationType, with two collections in it as:

```
->add('topay', 'collection', array(
  'required' => false,
  'type' => new TaTopayType(),
  'allow_add' => true,
  'allow_delete' => true,
  'by_reference' => false,
  'options' => array('data_class' => 'TA\ManagerBundle\Entity\TaTopay'), 
->add('client', 'collection', array(
  'required' => false,
  'type' => new TaClientType(),
  'allow_add' => true,
  'allow_delete' => true,
  'by_reference' => false,
  'options' => array('data_class' => 'TA\ManagerBundle\Entity\TaClient'),
```

And after deleting that collections, or changing

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('TA\ManagerBundle\Entity\TaReservation')->find($id);
```

to

```
$entity = new TaReservation();
```

Everything work allright - without data inside edited fields. Can anyone tell me how to repair that?

Answer (score 1):

[solved]

i find out, that one of the collections had a hidden field, with reservation id in it ;) deleting it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option "data_class" for "collection" form field, i dont know where you get that.

Check if in your form classes do you have the getDefaultOptions() method where you define your data class, like the example below:

```
 public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\EntityName',
    );
}
```

Comment: when i tried to use data_class for collection, on null i had the same, and, on value with entity even add form didn't work propertly...

getDefaultOptions - didn't work at all. i had already setDefaultOptions.

Comment: >The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class TA\ManagerBundle\Entity\TaTopay, but is an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection to an instance of TA\ManagerBundle\Entity\TaTopay. 


<--- After adding a data_class normally to both of collections on add entity.

Comment: >The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class TA\ManagerBundle\Entity\TaTopay, but is an instance of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection to an instance of TA\ManagerBundle\Entity\TaTopay. 

<--- After adding a data_class normally to both of collection on edit entity.